# MongoDB / PHP / MapReduce / Reg Exp / Strings->Floats

Tags: php, mongodb, mapreduce

I'm new with MapReduce, but I have a collection that I'd like to apply myself to as a chance to learn how mapreduce works.

Example Documents:

```
{ "filename" : "resume.doc",
  "folder"   : "work",
  "completed": "0.5" },

{ "filename" : "spreadsheet.xls",
  "folder"   : "work",
  "completed": "0.6" },

{ "filename" : "thesis.doc",
  "folder"   : "school",
  "completed": "0.75" },

{ "filename" : "coverletter.doc",
  "folder"   : "work",
  "completed": "0.6"}
```

So the whole idea is: I'd like to query:

```
{ "folder"   : "work", 
  "completed": { $gt: 0.5 }, 
  "filename" : new MongoRegex( "/\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/" ) }
```

And ultimately get the count of all documents by extension (.doc, .xls, etc.), as so:

```
{ ".doc" : 1,
  ".xls" : 1 }
```

I also realize i've got an issue because my %-completed are strings, not floats, so i think mongodb is going to need more instruction for comparing the strings.

I'm using (if it matters):

```
PHP extension: mongo/1.5.7
MongoDB: version 3.2.11
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems I've stumbled upon my own answer.
Let me know if anybody comes up with a more concise/expert solution. 
But this seems to work.

```
try {

$map = new MongoCode(

    'function(){ 
        var re = new RegExp(/(.+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,})$/);
        doctype = this.value.match(re);
        if(parseFloat(this.completed)>0.5){
            emit(doctype[2], parseFloat(this.completed));
        }
    }'

);

$reduce = new MongoCode(

    'function(key, values){ 
        var sum = 0, num = 0;
        for(var i in values){
            if(parseFloat(values[i])>0.5){
                sum += values[i];
                num += 1;
            }
        }
        return { number_of_documents :         num, 
                 sum_of_document_completions : sum, 
                 average_completion :          (sum/num) }; 
    }'

);

$query = array (
        "folder"    => "work"
);

$doctypes = $db->command( 
        array(
            'mapReduce'     => 'mydocuments',
            "map"           => $map,
            "reduce"        => $reduce,
            "query"         => $query,
            "out"           => array("inline"=>1)
        )
);

print_r ( $doctypes);

}
catch(MongoCursorException $e) {
     echo "error message: ".$e->getMessage()."\n";
     echo "error code: ".$e->getCode()."\n";
}
```